# implicit coercion in javascript

Tags: javascript, coercion, type-coercion

I am revisiting implicit coercion in javascript and realized that I have overlooked something and need clarification on it.

if

```
var a = "5";
var b = 5;
```

and `a==b` will return `true`.

But there are two possible ways `a==b` could give true coercion right? It's either `5 == 5`, or `'5' == '5'`. So which one is actually happening for the above example here?

Comment: Type coercion when comparing using `==` is implemented based on this ECMAScript spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: check [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) in the spec, specifically:

> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.

*(The `!` before `ToNumber(x)` does not mean negation, it's a spec notation asserting that `ToNumber(x)` will never result in an abrupt termination.)*

It's a numeric comparison, `"5"` is converted to `5` and then the comparison is done.

Comment: May I know what is the purpose of the abrupt terminations symbol to be put there? Looks confusing to me at the first place.

Comment: @tnkh - It's covered [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands): *"Similarly, prefix ! is used to indicate that the following invocation of an abstract or syntax-directed operation will never return an abrupt completion and that the resulting Completion Record's [[Value]] field should be used in place of the return value of the operation."* Follow the link for the long version of what that `!` would need to be when making the assertion explicitly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on abstract equality comparison algorithm, operands will be attempted to convert to number first. So the string `'5'` will be attempted to be converted to number `5`.

Take a look at the steps 6 and 7 in [abstract equality algorithm.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) No matter what type present against the number, the operand against the number will be converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

This is described here :

[2019 EcmaScript specifications - Abstract equality comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1) If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>           Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
>
> 2) If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>
> 3) If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
>
> 4) **If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).**
>
> 5) **If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.**
>
> (...)

So the string is converted to number, then compared.

This can be proved by the following code :

```
"" == 0 // true
0 == "" // true
```

Both return true, because empty string is coerced as the number 0.

If this was the other way around, 0 would become "0" (for 0 == "0" to be also true) and the comparison with empty string would return false

Comment: Just FWIW, that's quite an old specification to be linking to. That's ES2015. We're on ES2019 now, but in general I'd suggest linking to [the living specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point, I'm using my hard link in bookmarks, time to update